# Unix cut/ awk: Print same column multiple times (e.g. 1000 times)

Tags: linux, unix, awk, cut

How to copy a column for multiple times?

e.g.

Input

```
1   4771131 4772199 ENSMUSG00000103922  0   +   0.670011
1   4773206 4785739 ENSMUSG00000033845  0   -   95.0352
1   4778063 4779212 ENSMUSG00000102275  0   -   0.1806
1   4807788 4848410 ENSMUSG00000025903  0   +   110.078
```

Output

```
1   4771131 4772199 ENSMUSG00000103922  0   +   0.670011    0.670011 x 998 times
1   4773206 4785739 ENSMUSG00000033845  0   -   95.0352 95.0352 x 998 times
1   4778063 4779212 ENSMUSG00000102275  0   -   0.1806  0.1806 x 998 times
1   4807788 4848410 ENSMUSG00000025903  0   +   110.078 110.078 x 998 times
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, so you want to print 998 times last column or multiply it 998 times? As of now my answer is simply printing last column 998 times only.

Answer (score 1):

With simple for loop and printing the lines how many times you want to:

```
awk '{printf $0;for(i=1;i<=998;i++){printf("%s%s",$NF,i==998?"":" ")};print ""}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`, change variable `n=<your_interest>` value, according to your need.

**One-liner:**

```
 awk -v col=1 -v n=2 'function repeat(v, n,i){for(i=1; i<=n; i++)printf("%s%s",(i==1?"":OFS),v)}{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)printf("%s%s",(i==col?repeat($i,n):$i),i==NF?RS:OFS)}' infile
```

**Input:**

```
$ cat infile
1   4771131 4772199 ENSMUSG00000103922  0   +   0.670011
1   4773206 4785739 ENSMUSG00000033845  0   -   95.0352
1   4778063 4779212 ENSMUSG00000102275  0   -   0.1806
1   4807788 4848410 ENSMUSG00000025903  0   +   110.078
```

> When `col=7 and v=5`

```
$ awk -v col=7 -v n=5 'function repeat(v, n,i){for(i=1; i<=n; i++)printf("%s%s",(i==1?"":OFS),v)}{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)printf("%s%s",(i==col?repeat($i,n):$i),i==NF?RS:OFS)}' infile
1 4771131 4772199 ENSMUSG00000103922 0 + 0.670011 0.670011 0.670011 0.670011 0.670011
1 4773206 4785739 ENSMUSG00000033845 0 - 95.0352 95.0352 95.0352 95.0352 95.0352
1 4778063 4779212 ENSMUSG00000102275 0 - 0.1806 0.1806 0.1806 0.1806 0.1806
1 4807788 4848410 ENSMUSG00000025903 0 + 110.078 110.078 110.078 110.078 110.078
```

> Suppose if you set first column that is `col=1`, then

```
$ awk -v col=1 -v n=5 'function repeat(v, n,i){for(i=1; i<=n; i++)printf("%s%s",(i==1?"":OFS),v)}{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)printf("%s%s",(i==col?repeat($i,n):$i),i==NF?RS:OFS)}' infile
1 1 1 1 1 4771131 4772199 ENSMUSG00000103922 0 + 0.670011
1 1 1 1 1 4773206 4785739 ENSMUSG00000033845 0 - 95.0352
1 1 1 1 1 4778063 4779212 ENSMUSG00000102275 0 - 0.1806
1 1 1 1 1 4807788 4848410 ENSMUSG00000025903 0 + 110.078
```

**Better Readable:**

```
awk -v col=7 -v n=5 '
                     function repeat(v, n,i)
                     {
                       for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
                            printf("%s%s",(i==1?"":OFS),v)
                     }
                     {
                       for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
                         printf("%s%s",(i==col?repeat($i,n):$i),i==NF?RS:OFS)
                     }
                   ' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

**Awk** solution (with single `print` action):

```
awk '{ n=998;r=$NF; while(--n) r=r FS $NF; print $0,r}' OFS='\t' file
```

Comment: Just curious - why write `n=998; while(--n) foo` instead of `for (n=1;n<=998;n++) foo`?

Answer (score 1):

It gets very easy in **awk** with the power of formatted strings.

For ex.

```
$ awk -v count=3 '{s=sprintf("%0*s",count,""); gsub(/ /," "$NF,s); printf $0 s "\n"}' file
1   4771131 4772199 ENSMUSG00000103922  0   +   0.670011 0.670011 0.670011 0.670011
1   4773206 4785739 ENSMUSG00000033845  0   -   95.0352 95.0352 95.0352 95.0352
1   4778063 4779212 ENSMUSG00000102275  0   -   0.1806 0.1806 0.1806 0.1806
1   4807788 4848410 ENSMUSG00000025903  0   +   110.078 110.078 110.078 110.078
```

You can modify it to `count=999` for your desired output.

Comment: @AkshayHegde:  Thanks. To correct you, we don't need `gsub(/./," "$NF,s)` as it will replace each char which we don't want. We only want to replace the `format specifiers`. To verify it you can append a string to formatted string say `s=s"hello"` and now `gsub(/./," "$NF,s)` This will replace each char including `h` `e` `l` `l` `o` but if you use `gsub(/ /," "$NF,s)` it will only replace your specifiers before `hello`. Probably this will work in this example as the string has just specifiers in it but this is not what I want.